# OpenCV face detection error on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2017, opencv3.1

I've just installed Visual Studio (2017 Community) and OpenCV (3.4.1 win pack) , and I'm working with C++. So I just attempted to copy one of the sample codes of OpenCV from its source folder, but I faced this error:

[image]

Then I tried reinstalling the same version of OpenCV, but nothing changed.
So I just decided to download another version of OpenCV, I downloaded OpenCV  2.4.13.5 , and there's another error now:

[image]

Any ideas/suggestions?

Edit:

So I made these changes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dGjJ.png)

and got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gtk9.png)

which is right, it really doesn't exist:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrGTt.png)

So..was such file supposed to exist in that folder? (and btw I can't even find it in any other folder)

Comment: put the linked dlls in your build dir

Comment: @codekaizer could you explain a bit more detailed? Like where exactly and what exactly should I add to the project properties (If I'm right?) ? I'm just so beginner in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for configuring a visual studio project to be able to run opencv.

First after installing opencv go to the folder where you installed it, for me it's  `C:\opencv34` denote this by `<your path>`.

There navigate to `<your path>\build\x64\vc15\bin` and copy both `opencv_world340.dll` and `opencv_world340d.dll` into the directory where your project is saved.

Then in your project go to `Project->Properties->C\C++->General`.
In `Additional Include Directories` add `<your path>\include`

Finally go to `Project->Properties->Linker`.
Under `General->Additional Library Directories` add `<your path>\x64\vc15\lib`
and under `Input\Additional dependencies` add `opencv_world340.lib` for release configuration and `opencv_world340d.lib` for debug configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did just as you said, and made changes in the description of my post. It now says the .exe file doesn't exist in the <project>/x64/debug folder and that system can't find it. What do I do now?